# PCD Sample Data

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am looking for sample point cloud scenes to work with  but unable to find any free sample PCD data apart from the PCL Documentation with a few files. Any source when I can find free PCD files to work with? I am mainly working on ground and pedestrian recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Community Data Repositories links on this page
http://pointclouds.org/media/

Comment: The URL is not available now :(

Comment: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/test